# How to bake lightmap to a simplified duplicate object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I am importing models from magicavoxel, and then lighting them in blender. I have a high-res model which contains all the materials (as vertex colors) and emitters.

[image]

It renders nicely in cycles:

[image]

I've worked out how to duplicate the mesh, remove materials and "remove doubles" then "limited dissolve" to create a low poly version of the mesh.

[image]

However - I can't work out how to bake from the high res mesh to the low res mesh. I have tried going to "cycles settings" on the low poly standin and disabling "Camera" from Ray Visibility - but when I bake the texture - I just get a big green smudge, I can't see any of the vertex colors baked into the standin:

[image]

Can someone explain to me how I should use cycles to bake the lightmap onto the low-poly duplicate?

Comment: When you use Limited Dissolve, you need to enable UVs, in the operator panel in Delimit section.

Comment: I am adding the lightmap UVs after the limited dissolve. :)

Answer (score 1):

Limited dissolve with default settings, in most cases can destroy the UV map.
To avoid that you need to enable UVs, in the operator panel in Delimit section.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, it was to select 'Selected to Active' under bake settings, and select both the high resolution and low resolution models and it happily baked. Looks great. <3 Blender.